# Prevent conda from automatically downgrading python package

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, pandas-datareader, conda-forge

I had [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63894169/pandas-datareader-importerror-cannot-import-name-urlencode/65377788#65377788) with `pandas-datareader` package v0.8.1. To fix my problem, I had to upgrade the package to a newer version 0.9 by running the following command:

```
conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader
```

Unfortunately, when I tried to upgrade conda packages later using the command `conda update --all`, `pandas-datareader` is downgraded back to v0.8.1. v0.8.1 is [from conda-forge channel](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pandas-datareader). What I want is the v0.9 [from anaconda channel](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pandas-datareader).

How do I force conda to always upgrade pandas-datareader to the latest version in anaconda channel when I run `conda update --all`?

I am using python anaconda 2020_07 version on Windows 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Specify Minimum Version

Conda is sufficiently powerful to parse minimum versions, and it remembers that they've been specified. If you would prefer 0.9 as the minimum, then you just need to say so with

```
conda install 'pandas-datareader>=0.9'
```

or

```
conda install pandas-datareader[version='>=0.9']
```

Once you've run this, it will be added into your *explicit specifications*,<sup>**1**</sup> and that should lock in at least that version of `pandas-datareader`, including in subsequent `conda update --all` runs.<sup>**2**</sup> [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57734390/570918) has a fuller description of Conda's MatchSpec system, which covers the scope of what can be specified.

#### Channel Specifications

Although this isn't what OP effectively wants, it may be worth elaborating why the channel switching happened and how a channel can also be explicitly specified.
The `--channel|-c` flag only adds (and prioritizes) a channel during the command it is used with. It does not tell Conda that a particular package should come from that channel. Hence, since OP likely has **conda-forge** prioritized over **defaults** in their global/user configuration (see `conda config --show channels`), running `conda update --all` will simply switch back to whatever the most recently uploaded build is.

To explicitly indicate that a package should come from a channel, one should instead use

```
conda install anaconda::pandas-datareader
```

This will then add `anaconda::pandas-datareader` into the explicit specifications, and that should lock in the fact that one expects `pandas-datareader` to come from the **anaconda** channel.

#### Package Pinning

Otherwise, [package pinning](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#preventing-packages-from-updating-pinning) could be another option.

---

<sub>**[1]** One can check explicit specifications with `conda env export --from-history`.</sub>

<sub>**[2]** Be aware that some flags may override explicit specifications without warning, such as `--update-deps`.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. I have verified by testing that `conda install 'pandas-datareader>=0.9'` will fix the problem. Marked as correct answer.