# Recommended way to install and update packages from different channels in conda

Tags: python, conda

Conda does a good job [explaining what are channels and how to use them](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/channels.html). However, I never know what to do when I want to install packages from different channels.

For example, most packages recommend installation via the `conda-forge` (i.e. [`xarray`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/getting-started-guide/installing.html#instructions)). However, I occasionally encounter a package that uses a different channel (like [HoloViews](https://holoviews.org/install.html)). Whenever I encounter those packages from different channels, chances are relatively high that `conda` will find some conflicts that it can't solve. If that's the case, what's the preferred way of resolving them?

Also, how do I update these packages? Should I update them all individually specifying their respective channels?

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65386464/570918 Not really a recommendation though - more showing possibilities.