# How to import pandas_datareader?

Tags: python, pandas, importerror, pandas-datareader

I cannot import *pandas_datareader* due to the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'urlencode' from 'pandas.io.common'

How can I solve this problem?

I know that this question has already been asked, for instance here [pandas_datareader, ImportError: cannot import name 'urlencode'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63894169/pandas-datareader-importerror-cannot-import-name-urlencode)
but the solutions proposed there seem to not worked for me.

It's also possible that I am applying them in the wrong way (see below) but I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you very much for your help.

Some additional info:

1. I'm using Python 3.9.1
2. I have *pandas_datareader* 0.9 (the most recent version) according to Anaconda but pandas.show_versions() does not find any pandas_datareader module installed
3. I have *pandas* 1.2.1 according to Anaconda (checked typing *conda list* in the terminal); but using the function *pandas.show_versions()* in the console it says me that I am using pandas 1.2.2  (A clarification also on this point is appreciated)
4. I have tried (with no success) this solution suggested in a similar question:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like

import pandas_datareader
```

5. I have also tried (with no success) this other solution suggested in a similar question:
   replace

```
from pandas.io.common import urlencode
```

with

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
```

in the file pandas_datareader/iex/**init**.py and pandas_datareader/base.py but I have checked the files and they are already correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas\_datareader, ImportError: cannot import name 'urlencode'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63894169/pandas-datareader-importerror-cannot-import-name-urlencode)

Comment: No unfortunately it does not. I have tried the solutions proposed there but with no success.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall pandas and making sure both are of the latest versions? It might be some compatibility issue.

Comment: Yes, I have created a new conda environment in which I have reinstalled pandas_datareader  but I have the same problem.

Comment: I just created a fresh conda environment for python3.9.1 and installed pandas-datareader, no issue for me and I'm not getting the error. What is the pandas version you are using?

Comment: pandas 1.2.2  and pandas_datareader 0.9, and you?

Comment: Same, so I have no idea what went wrong from all the information you provided and can't reproduce the error.